# MSAL authentication fails in iOS simulator with the message - requires you to secure this device before you can access company email, files and data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, azure, azure-ad-msal

I have tried MSAL authentication in iOS simulator it redirects to the below added screens. Do I need to change anything while I test MSAL authentication in iOS Simulator to bypass this screen or Do I need to do anything in Azure/Intune Portal?

Xcode Version: 11.3

Mac OS: macOS Monterey 12.2.1

[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]
[image: Screen 3]

**I have added these keys in plist:**
[image: plist keys]

**Added these frameworks:**
[image: Frameworks]

Comment: Yes, App is registered on the Azure portal. @Dilan

Comment: Your azure AD has conditional access rules that require your device to be registered with intune and managed. This is not possible on the simulator. You will either need to test on a real device that is managed or get your admins to change the authentication policies for your app.